# Viral Load and Antiretroviral Therapy Dataset

Tags: public-databases, covid-19, data-retrieval, virus, data-mining

My project is on Mathematical Modeling of the relationship between viral load and antiretroviral therapy. Its purely an academic investigation which is exploratory in nature.

**Question** I am seeking a public-database or a published data set for drug-HIV interactions and in particular drug vs viral load, for example a time series.

**Project** Intend using the different orthogonal polynomials to fit the curve and then test them statistically to know which fits best.

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Which curve do you want to fit? To which data? Or are you asking us to where to find data of antiretrovirals and viral load?